# Obtaining data from log file in c# program

Tags: c#

I am trying to work out how to create a c# program that can view the data in a log file that is always updating with new data. The data within the log file looks like the below:

> CPU2: memory5 ( 50070 )CPU3: drive7 ( 500 )CPU6: memory10( 1000)CPU2:
>   memory5 ( 50700 )CPU2: memory5 ( 60070 )CPU3: drive7 ( 500 )CPU6:
>   memory10( 1000)CPU2: memory5 ( 70000 )CPU3: drive7 ( 500 )CPU6:
>   memory10( 1000).

Once the data is read from the log file, I would like the ability to list the latest data from the log file, example for `memory5`, including the data before it, `[CPU2:]` and the data after it, `[70000]` so that the program would constantly be monitoring the log file and reporting the latest data from the above for `memory5`, it would show `CPU2: memory5 (70000)`

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void LoadFile()
{
    try
    {
        using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
            "logs/myapp.log",
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                this.textBoxLogs.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading log file: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

There's a very useful blog post about how to do this: [Read a file that is in use](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2009/04/How-do-I-open-a-file-that-is-in-use-in-C.aspx)

Comment: The below is what I have at the moment but I do not yet have an understanding of how to filter the text and to only see the latest figures in the log next to the specified text.

Comment: class searchTxt
{
        
public static void Main()
{
var lockMe = new object();
using (var latch = new ManualResetEvent(true))
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\logfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\"))
{
fsw.Changed += (s, e) =>
{
lock (lockMe)
{
if (e.FullPath != @"C:\logfile.txt") return;
latch.Set();
}
};
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
latch.WaitOne();
lock (lockMe)
{
String line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
Console.Out.WriteLine(line);
latch.Set();
}
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: Store the Length property of your FileStream when you read the log.  the next time you read the log check that the Length of the FileStream to ensure it's longer than it was previously and then set the Position of the open FileStream to the Length taken previously.    This will mean that all data you read is new.  You should be able to take this from here.